# Git commit saying no changes commited

Tags: github, commit

Okay. So I've got forked repository from my college teacher. I need to change `main.cpp`, then commit and push changes. I've done something like this:

`git config --global user.name "username"` and same thing with e-mail

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email"`

`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

And then I did: `git clone adress` (SSH). Files were copied correctly. I've edited my main.cpp, saved changes, and then did: `git commit -m "Solution"` and `git push`. This is my terminal:

[image: Cloning]

And here I edit `main.cpp`. Then:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might forget     git add .

Comment: after "git add something" its always best practice to check "git status" before doing "git commit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to stage files for commit. Learn more about staging with git in [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/).

> The git add command adds a change in the working directory to the
>   staging area. It tells Git that you want to include updates to a
>   particular file in the next commit. However, git add doesn't really
>   affect the repository in any significant way—changes are not actually
>   recorded until you run git commit.

In your case, just before the commit do:

```
git add main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

after your changes to source code, you need to do

```
git add .
git commit -m "Solution"
```

to upload you commits to remote

```
git push origin yourbranch
```